# Simple extensions being well-defined.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field and let $\alpha\notin F$

We define
$$
F(\alpha) = \{f(\alpha)/g(\alpha) : f,g\in F[x], \hspace{0.15cm} g(\alpha) \neq 0\}
$$
as the smallest field containing both $F$ and $\alpha$.

How can we morally allow $f, g$ to take inputs from outside its domain? Say I have
$$
f(x) = c_0 + c_1x + \ldots + c_nx^n.
$$
Thus,
$$
f(\alpha) = c_0 + c_1\alpha + \ldots + c_n\alpha^n.
$$

How can we evaluate this expression if $\alpha\notin F$?

In the case where $F = \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha = i$, I understand how this works, but mainly since $i$ is defined in terms of radicals and integers, for which we already know how they interact with $i$.

But I can't understand why this holds in general? Like what if I had $\mathbb{R}(T)$, where
$T$ is some binary tree. I don't see how a polynomial could take a graph as an input?

Comment: *Morally* has nothing to do in this context.

Comment: Your question is lacking some context. Either $F$ is a subfield of $F \subseteq G$ and $\alpha$ belongs to $G$. Then $f(\alpha)$ is well defined for any $f \in F[x]$. Otherwise $f(\alpha)$ has no meaning.

Comment: This depends on whether $\alpha$ is algebraic or transcendental over $F$. For transcendental $\alpha $ treat it as indeterminate and for algebraic $\alpha$ you are actually dealing with the field $F[x] /(p(x)) $ where $p(x) $  is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

If you write $F(\alpha)$, then $\alpha$ must be an element of some bigger field (or at least ring) containing $F$ and $\alpha$, so that it makes sense to write $c_0+c_1α +\dots +c_n α^n$.

The expression "the smallest field containing both $F$ and $α$" does not really make sense in itself, it must be "the smallest subfield of $R$" where $R$ is some ring with $F\subset R$ and $\alpha\in R$ (and $\alpha$ must then be invertible in $R$, or else you can only define $F[\alpha]$).

Or else $\alpha$ is an indeterminate, and then $F(\alpha)$ is defined formally (as a field of rational functions in the indeterminate $\alpha$).